# Read string array from internal storage

Tags: java, android, arrays, storage, internal

I have been searched on the forum for a while now, but can't find my question. I see a lot of examples of how to write a String Array to internal storage, but not how to read them again.

I have a String Array which is saved by:

```
String FILENAME = "data1";
fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
for(int j=1;j<=PupilAmount;j++) {  
    fos.write(pup[j].getBytes());  
} 
fos.close();
```

But how do I read the variables again, and save it in a new variable on my new Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string array is serializable. So you can serialize it on a file

```
FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
oos.writeObject(pup);
oos.close();
```

and read back this way:

```
FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
String[] pup = (String[]) ois.readObject();
ois.close()
```

Comment: Wow. That sounds easy. Is the file able to contain multiple Objects in this way then?

Comment: yes, also complex object but it is mandatory that those objects implements the serializable interface, otherwise they can not be write